# How to connect to DogitalOcean Droplets database with MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean, flask-mongoengine, mongodb-compass

I have a flask app with mongoDB running on a digital ocean's droplet, and now I need to see what's inside that database.

I'm trying to connect with mongoDBCompass, but no tutorial seems to help me.

If there's another easier way to access that data, it would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

Connect MongoDB Compass via an [SSH tunnel](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/connect/).

Or use SSH tunneling with e.g.:

```
ssh -L <local_port>:<mongodb_hostname>:<mongodb_port> <user>@<bastion_hostname> -fN
```

and connect MongoDB Compass via `localhost:<local_port>`.

Or use the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) directly on your droplet.

Or open the mongo port (typically 27017) via an inbound [firewall](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/create/) rule and connect your favorite client to your droplets public IP.